# How to print in reverse in assembly language using DOSBox Debug?

Tags: string, assembly, reverse, dos, x86-16

This is one of the examples my instructor gave me but I need to find a way to reverse the order of what I input.

Here's the code:

```
e200 "Name: $"
e300 "Hello, $"
a100
mov ah, 09
mov dx, 200
int 21
mov bx, 400
mov ah, 01
int 21
mov [bx], al
inc bx
cmp bx, 405
jne 10a
mov cl, 24
mov [bx], cl
mov ah, 02
mov dl, 0a
int 21
mov dl, 0d
int 21
mov ah, 09
mov dx, 300
int 21
mov ah, 09
mov dx, 400
int 21
int 20
```

Output is:

```
Name: Maria
Hello, Maria
```

Expected Output (reverse):

```
Name: Maria
Hello, ariaM
```

Comment: Your example assumes a 5-byte name that does not contain a dollar sign. It would be better to use interrupt 21h service 0Ah to get input, and either service 40h (file handle 1 in bx for stdout) or service 02h to write output. Your example already uses interrupt 21h service 02h, do you understand what it does?

Comment: @ecm: sorry I'm completely new to this language and I am not sure what other interrupts do, I am still exploring tbh but I'll try what you said about getting input and writing output. Thank u

Comment: @ecm: i now understand int21 service 0ah but i am still confused at writing the output. also, how can i write/print it (the input) in a reverse order?

Comment: Read the reply I posted. You can mark it as accepted if it answers your questions.

Comment: You can reverse the string, in a copy to another string, or, reverse it in place, either way, then print it forwards.  Or, you can print the last character first, then the next to last character and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on current lDebug and (creating the executable only) on Microsoft's Debug from MS-DOS version 2 (available under MIT license). This should solve your task.

```
f 100 4FF 90
a 100
 mov ah, 09
 mov dx, 500
 int 21
 mov ah, 0A
 mov dx, 800
 int 21
 mov ah, 09
 mov dx, 600
 int 21
 xor cx, cx
 mov cl, [801]
 mov bx, cx
 add bx, 801
 jcxz 190

a 130
 mov ah, 02
 mov dl, [bx]
 int 21
 dec bx
 loop 130

a 190
 mov ah, 09
 mov dx, 700
 int 21
 mov ax, 4C00
 int 21

e 800 FF 0 0D
e 500 "Name: $"
e 600 0D 0A "Hello, $"
e 700 0D 0A "$"
g
q
```

1. 800 up to below 901 holds a maximum size buffer for interrupt 21h service 0Ah, which we initialise to FF (buffer size 255), 0 (nothing to recall), 0D (indicate end of recallable input).
2. 500, 600, and 700 contain dollar-terminated messages to be used with interrupt 21h service 09h.
3. The output loop counter is initialised to CX = CL = length in bytes of input line, as returned by service 0Ah, excluding the final Carriage Return.
4. The offset to output is initialised to BX = 801 + CX, which is the same as 802 + CX - 1. 802 is the address of the first byte of the returned input. 802 + CX is the address **behind** the last byte of the returned input. The minus one serves as an adjustment to point at the last byte instead of behind it.
5. `jcxz` skips the loop for empty names.
6. `mov dl, [bx]` loads a byte into the low half of DX.
7. Interrupt 21h service 02h is used to output a byte.
8. `dec bx` decrements the offset stored in BX.
9. The `loop 130` instruction decrements CX and jumps back if the resulting CX is non-zero.
10. The `f` command is to fill a part of the code segment with all `nop` instructions. Along with the different `a` commands this allows us to place and use fixed offsets for jump targets in the code, without having to know exactly how long each instruction will be.
11. Enter the name input, then indicate its end using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

To generate an executable, prepend the command `f 100 9FF 0`, then instead of the `g` command run this:

```
r bx
 0
r cx
 900
n test.com
w 100
q
```

Comment: I uploaded the script file to write an executable to https://pushbx.org/ecm/test/20220615/writexec.sld along with a few additional files. Run `ldebug /c='y writexec.sld'` or `debug < writexec.sld` to use it.

Comment: It worked! You're a life saver! thank you so much<3. Sorry to bother you T_T